# Why there is difference in Dense layer input_shapes while fitting and predicting model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am learning TF and trying to implement following code

```
window_size = 4
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(window_size,))
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([layer])

model.compile(...)
model.fit(dataset,epochs=100,verbose=0)
```

So in Dense() layer my input_shape is (4,)
then why does this
 `model.predict(np.array([4,5,3,2]))`
not work?
And `model.predict(np.array([4,5,3,2])[None])` this works?
If the mentioned input_shape is (4,)  then while predicting why does it need (1,4)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `input_shape` denotes the number of features pre sample.
- We use mini-batch Gradient decent for training, so we send a batch of
  samples (denoted by `batch_size`) at a time for training . Since this
  batch can vary depending on the specs of the machine and the dataset,
  we do not fix it with in the model. More over, model architecture does
  not depend on the number of samples but rather depends on the number
  of input features per sample.
- `model.predict(np.array([4,5,3,2]))` will not work because you are predicting on 4 samples of one feature each but your `input_shape` is of 4 features per sample.
- You can make predictions on  data of size `n X 4` where `n` are number of sample and each samples has `4` features.

Comment: @ mujjiga, thanks for the reply. Does that mean we always have to send BatchDataset for training?

Comment: @you will always train/predict in batches. Lets say your data size is `100 x 4` i.e 100 samples each of 4 features, and you are using the `fit` method of keras you will set the `batch_size` to say 8. Internally the `fit` method will pass in 8 samples at a time. Same for predictions. If you have only one sample you should send in as shape `1 X 4`.

Comment: Thanks. One more followup question, please. My dataset has 2 columns, one for input features(X) and one for label(Y). I am passing entire dataset to fit() model and its nowhere mentioned what is X and what is Y. How does model interpret that?

Comment: @Neo you are doing it wrong. Inside `fit` the first argument is features `X` and the second argument is the label `Y`.  Check the docs https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Comment: My approach is also correct: as per the doc:  'If x is a dataset, generator, or keras.utils.Sequence instance, y should not be specified (since targets will be obtained from x).' Thanks

Comment: @Neo, in case it is a generator, it should implement `__getitem__` method which returns two value of form `X, y`. Here the x parameters of the method is a generator and the call to the generator will return both `X,y` that is the reason docs say `since targets will be obtained from x`